# Delay in retrieving data from Ionic 2 storage

Tags: ionic2, local-storage

Before I launches the app I will check with local storage if any user data available, If yes I will navigation to Home page else Login page.

Here I'm unable to retrieve stored data, Any inputs please...

Currently using Ionic 2 SQlite plugin.

Note: In browser it's working fine but on Android device it's not working.

### app.component.ts : checking user data

```
loadUser() {
        this.userSettings.getUser().then(user => {
            this.userObj = JSON.stringify(user);
            if (user) {
                console.log('App : ', this.userObj);
                this.nav.setRoot(HomePage,this.userObj);

            } else {
                console.log('App : No user data');
                this.rootPage = LoginPage;
            }

        });

    }
```

### login.ts : Saving user data

```
this.userSettings.addUser(
                            userData.employeeCode,
                            userData.password,
                            userData.role
                        );
```

### user-settings.ts : Storage file in providers

```
getUser() {
        if (this.sql) {
            return this.sql.get('user').then(value => value);
        } else {
            return new Promise(resolve =>                 resolve(this.storage.get('user').then(value => value)));
        }
}

addUser(employeeCode, password, role) {
        let item = { employeeCode: employeeCode, password: password, role: role };

        if (this.sql) {
            this.sql.set('user', JSON.stringify(item)).then(data => {
                this.events.publish('userObj:changed');
            });
        } else {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                this.storage.set('user', JSON.stringify(item)).then(() => {
                    this.events.publish('userObj:changed');
                    resolve();
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

### app.module.ts:

```
providers: [
        { provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler },
        AuthService,
        SqlStorage,
        UserSettings,
        Storage
    ]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide some code on how you are using sqlite plugin if possible

Comment: Cannot pinpoint the problem without having a code sample from your code. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Problem solved**

After calling the sqlite operation in **ngAfterViewInit** it's working fine.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.storage.get('user').then((user: any) => {
            if (user) {

                this.userCredentials = JSON.parse(user);

                this.nav.setRoot(HomePage, this.userCredentials);

            }
            else {
                this.rootPage = LoginPage;
            }
        });
    }
```

[Source] (https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/pages/account/account.ts)

Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

As you point out that your code is working in Chrome, but not on your device, you might be calling sqlite before cordova's  device.ready() has fired.

In app.component.ts ensure you call this.loadUser() in the following manner: 
(platform.ready() should already be in the constructor)

```
 platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.loadUser();
    });
```

Comment: I'm following the same way, Here is my app.component.ts

        platform.ready().then(() => {
            // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
            // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
            StatusBar.styleDefault();

            Splashscreen.hide();

            storage.ready().then(() => {

                console.log('Storage ready ...');

                this.userSettings.initStorage().then(() => {
                    this.loadUser();
                });

            });

        });